# Intersystems Cache ODBC

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have been struggling to generate a Crystal Report with an ODBC connection to a Cache database for a week now.
The problem is that I need to send dynamic queries to the database, based on user input. The queries in itself are working, but I cannot seem to get the data that is returned into a dataset into a crystal report.

Kind regards
Tommy

Comment: Can you expand on "...I cannot seem to get the data that is returned..."? What happens when you run the report? How do you know the queries are working?

Comment: Working on an Epic project?

Comment: I can see what is in my dataset with visualizer, and did test the queries with RazorSQL, thus knowing that the correct data is returned to my DS.